# Remove weird arrows in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I get weird arrows in coding when pasting the code from another editor
How can i delete them?

[image]

Comment: That looks like you might have "show whitespaces" enabled somewhere in Android Studio settings.

Comment: @CommonsWare That was interesting and i've tried "show whitespaces" option which enables **dots** on AS 3.1.3 and not arrows. Not sure about the AS v3.0.

Comment: @Mohsen dots represent spaces, arrows represent tabs. It depends on how you indent your code, and OP has apparently mixed both.

Comment: Perhaps check under `File` → `Settings` → `Editor` → `Code Style` to see what 'Tabs and Indents' coding format is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Found it.

Go to `File` → `Settings` → `Editor` → `Code Style` → `Java` and uncheck "**Use tab character**".

[image]

*Thanks to Floern to mention about the tab one!*

---

If there were dots, you may want to uncheck `show whitespaces` from:

`File` → `Settings` → `Editor` → `General` → `Appearance` → `Show white Spaces` too.